# monitor tomcat executor?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

How do I get a reference to the Tomcat Executor instances running within the web app? I need this so I can query basic information, such as thread pool size and utilization.

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer but I'd recommend to use JMX for this. To get a list of `MBeans` matching various criteria, use the `MBeanServerConnection.queryNames()` method. For example, to return a list of all the `ThreadPool` MBeans, use `queryNames(new ObjectName("Catalina:type=ThreadPool,*", null))`.